# Depois do beta público o que muda?

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, beta

O que muda depois que o SOPT sair do beta público? Os 90 dias mínimos já estão acabando, há previsão de quando tempo iremos ficar em beta (ou de quais requisitos faltam para sairmos do beta)?

Comment: Eu imaginei que o beta durasse apenas 90 dias, vi que são no mínimo 90 dias depois do comentário do @mgibsonbr!

Comment: Pergunta relacionada, postada durante o beta privado e nunca respondida em detalhes (alguns pontos chegaram a ser citados no chat, mas no meta, nada): http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/como-nosso-site-sera-graduado

Comment: Ainda nada sobre isto?

Comment: De interesse: 
[Code Review Graduation](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2526/14985)

Answer (score 7):

Não é uma resposta oficial, apenas minha visão:

Bastante pouca coisa nos falta para alcançar a graduação completa.

1. Existem ainda alguns poucos problemas de tradução, localização e layout a serem resolvidos. Espera-se que o site esteja totalmente localizado antes de sair do beta. (mesmo que sempre vá surgir pequenos problemas depois.)
2. O escopo do site ainda não está completamente definido. Tem surgido bastantes questões polêmicas em que não se sabe ao certo se devem ou não pertencer ao site. É interessante ter isso mais sólido e só se atinge esse objetivo com tempo, movimentação e perguntas.
3. Não temos usuários com reputação suficiente para ter todos os privilégios em um site graduado. Ter usuários com esses privilégios é importante para tornar possível a moderação comunitária que faz do SO o que ele é. Novamente apenas uma questão de tempo. (o site pode acabar sendo lançado com pontuação reduzida nos privilégios e só aumentar depois.)

Vale notar que **não há** mais (e provavelmente nunca houve) a possibilidade de o site não se graduar. Mas o procedimento é bastante diferenciado e único aqui. Somos diferentes.

Comment: As pontuações para os privilégios após graduação já foram definidas? Estão sendo discutidas em algum lugar?

Comment: @carlos Não. Isso é uma decisão interna da stackexchange. Os valores exatos não importam muito. Vão ser provavelmente uma proporção dos atuais.

Comment: Pelo que eu saiba, todo site tem a mesma tabela de pontuação. Veja no [so], [sf], [su] e outros sites graduados como é sempre a mesma coisa. E pelo que eu vi, todo site em beta público também tem a mesma tabela que este. Por esse raciocínio, só quando tivermos usuários com 10.000 de reputação é que sairíamos do beta... Não sei se é assim que funciona ou não, nunca acompanhei a graduação de um site. Em tempo: 90 dias é o **mínimo** necessário prum site sair do beta público - na prática, pode demorar bem mais (há sites que estão há mais de 3 anos ainda no beta).

Comment: Olhando os dois sites parece que não são exatamente as mesmas tabelas, veja no Server Fault que criar tags são só 300 pontos (o que seria adequado aqui no SOPT) mas no SOEN são 1500 pontos (talvez porque já existam muitas tags). Pensei que depois de 90 dias o site iria automaticamente sair do beta, quando saberemos se vai sair ou não?

Comment: @carloscinelli Acho que *quando* nem a Stack Exchange sabe ainda.

Comment: Saquei! Quais seriam os "requisitos" que precisaríamos para sair do beta?

Comment: @carloscinelli Vou deixar pro Gabe responder esta, só ele tem a posição oficial. Mas acredito que farão isso quando considerarem que o site "vingou", que a comunidade está firme, e que problemas técnicos e de tradução foram resolvidos.